# How to bind 2 tables to Gridview in order to use better column headings

Tags: vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have what is probably a common issue but just can't for the life of me think of a good way to do this.

The requirement is for the web site to read in an ftp file. No problem. The file is a CSV with first row header, that matches up with a table, where the CSV contains all or some sub set of the header values. The remaining CSV rows correspond to the header rows within said CSV. So inserting these records to the table is not expected to be an issue.

The issue is that the header rows are cryptic, A45D34, A45D35, A45D36, etc. (hundreds of columns). There is a corresponding CSV file that lists all of the column headings along with the corresponding display text to be used whenever a query is written against the table to display the data.

I am wondering if there is someway to take advantage of the SQLDATASOURCE and query both tables, one with the data and the other with the display text and bind it to, for example, a Gridview, or other display control within a web form .aspx page.

Any tutorials, examples, links, suggestions, or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED:** This is still in proof of concept so there is some flexibility in design though not much.

Tbl1:

```
 keyID  int
 CMR_03 decimal(9, 6)
 CMR_05 decimal(9, 6)
 Z_0E721AD  decimal(9, 3)
 Z_0E72280  decimal(9, 3)
 Z_0E7200C  decimal(9, 3)
```

Sample Data;

```
keyID   CMR_03        CMR_05     Z_0E721AD    Z_0E72280    Z_0E7200C
 1       82.234500    45.456700  1200.000     4.000    1500.000
 4       82.654100    44.654000  1150.000     8.000    6500.000
 6       83.654000    45.941000  1500.000     7.000    4500.000
 7       83.156000    45.984100  1551.000     6.000    3500.000
10       83.321000    45.885210  900.000      2.000    1200.000
```

Tbl2:

```
 keyID  int 
 tbl1ColName    nvarchar(50)
 displayText    nvarchar(50)
```

Sample Data:

```
1   CMR_03          Latitude
2   CMR_05          Longitude
3   Z_0E721AD   Torque
4   Z_0E72280   Calculated Position
5   Z_0E7200C   Speed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure of any tutorial but to suggest; pull both the excel/csv data to two different tables in database. Since you said, there is a corresponding CSV file that lists all of the column headings along with the corresponding display text to be used.

You can perform a `join` on both the table then as below and get the data along with proper header text. which then you can directly bind to the gridview.

```
select csv1_table.*,csv2_table.display_header
from csv1_table 
inner join csv2_table
on csv1_table.criptic_header = csv2_table.criptic_header
```

Comment: hmm, I'll give this a shot. I got the relationship down. Just wasn't sure about flexibility of the data source and Gridview formatting. I was leaning toward a custom control idea, but that's new to me.

Comment: @htm11h, Consider accepting the answer if it happens to be helpful to you.

Comment: I certainly will, I am testing some methods today to see if it will.

Comment: This certainly gets the proper column heading name into the data table, but I don't see a way to make the Gridview use that as the column headings.

Comment: Can you show few sample data from both the CSV/table for me to figure out what data the query will return. Edit your post and include the data.

Comment: Sure let me post some things. To note, the main table data does not have the cryptic col names in a columns, only the table schema.